# Formula parsing error when use Query and Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I need to import data from another sheet, **but only even-numbered rows** (**has a number in column A** in addition to the spreadsheet numbering).

I'm using `importrange` and `query` to make this filter, but I'm experiencing the following error: "Formula parsing error".

This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oI0NsjQnf1Grh59HSei64c5F6nuqnjyGSQCXvLJbcmA", "Página1!A2:J1000"),"SELECT * WHERE (A % 2) = 0")
```

This command only:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oI0NsjQnf1Grh59HSei64c5F6nuqnjyGSQCXvLJbcmA";"Página1!A2:J100")
```

works, so the problem would be with my Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1oI0NsjQnf1Grh59HSei64c5F6nuqnjyGSQCXvLJbcmA"; "Página1!A2:J"); 
 ISEVEN(IMPORTRANGE("1oI0NsjQnf1Grh59HSei64c5F6nuqnjyGSQCXvLJbcmA"; "Página1!A2:A")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It worked, thankss! Can you explain to me why the method I was trying to do didn't work?

Comment: several reasons but `(A % 2)` does not exist eg not valid syntax parameter